# Python novice; split a string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a patch for some open source software because it doesn't do *quite* what I'd like--except I don't know Python, at all!  I expect this is very simple, but it is defeating me.

**Background:** The patch I am writing is for Ganeti which I am using to manage KVM virtual machine clusters, but it doesn't support all the possible command line options of KVM and Qemu, such as USB pass-through, so I am trying to modify it to allow this.

`kvm_cmd.extend()` is used to add to the array of KVM CLI args that will be passed when a VM is started.  If the arguments are space-separated, each argument becomes a separate string, e.g. `-usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostdev=14` becomes `"-usb", "-device", "usb-host,hostbus=1,hostdev=14"`.

I am running the following command after compiling the code:

```
gnt-instance modify -H usb_pass="1;14"
```

I want this to add to the existing list of command line arguments `"-usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostdev=14"`.  This is the code I have added (as well as declaring the variables elsewhere; `HV_USBPASSTHROUGH` is a string, but this is where the magic happens)

```
usb_pass = instance.hvparams[constants.HV_USBPASSTHROUGH]
if usb_pass:
    usb_pass_arr = []
    usb_pass_arr = usb_pass.split(";")
    kvm_cmd.extend(["-usb", "-device", "usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" %
                    usb_pass_arr])
```

I am getting the following error from running the above command with the above code:  `Could not start instance: Error while executing backend function: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: How are you able to get Hypervisor config in python w/

instance.hvparams[constants.HV_USBPASSTHROUGH]?

$ gnt-instance modify --help
Usage
=====
gnt-instance modify <instance>

Alters the parameters of an instance

Options
=======
--debug, -d             Turn debugging on
--force, -f      Force the operation
--hypervisor=HYPERVISOR, -H HYPERVISOR Change hypervisor parameters
--backend=BEPARAMS, -B BEPARAMS Change backend parameters
--disk=DISKS     Disk changes
--net=NICS       NIC changes
--submit         Submit the job and return the job ID, but             don't wait for the job to finish

Comment: If I knew that much about Python I would be having this problem :) I will post an answer that is the full patch for USB pass through as this is now working thanks to the great guys and girls that have posted answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two `` `%s `` in `"usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s"` but provide only one argument, a list, where a tuple is expected.

use

`"usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" % tuple(usb_pass_arr)`

[tuple()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) builtin converts an iterable to a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
"usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" % usb_pass_arr
```

to

```
"usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" % tuple(usb_pass_arr)
```

Also the pre-initialization of `usb_pass_arr` is not needed, as `split()` returns a new list.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the answer for ["old" style formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) already; using [new style formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) with `.format()`, you could do the following using the [variable-length argument syntax](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) to automatically unpack `usb_pass` into function arguments for `format()`:

```
'usb-host,hostbus={},hostaddr={}'.format(*usb_pass)
```

Comment: Thank you for a thoughtful and useful edit @zigg

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is pass `usb_pass_arr` as a tuple, which is what [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) expects.

```
usb_pass = instance.hvparams[constants.HV_USBPASSTHROUGH]
if usb_pass:
    usb_pass_arr = [] #you can remove this line
    usb_pass_arr = tuple(usb_pass.split(";")) #a tuple is an immutable list
    kvm_cmd.extend(["-usb", "-device", "usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" %
                    usb_pass_arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

As people already wrote, you need to convert the list to a tuple using `tuple(usb_pass_arr)`.
See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) paragraph in the python docs:

> If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple object. Otherwise, values must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Cursory guess -- you need to use this instead:

```
"usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" % (usb_pass_arr[0], usb_pass_arr[1])
```

Comment: Oh. Derp. tuple() would work too. much cleaner that way.

Comment: Umm, not sure why the downvote - True that you don't "need to use" this approach, but it's completely valid and would solve the OP's question, so +1 from me to counter-act the -1

Answer (score 0):

Hi David Morton and anyone else that is interested, this is for Ganeti 2.6.0 USB pass-through of a single USB device per instance;

```
    diff -r -c ganeti-2.6.0_original/lib/constants.py ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/constants.py
*** ganeti-2.6.0_original/lib/constants.py  2012-07-27 12:31:48.000000000 +0100
--- ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/constants.py   2012-10-04 13:46:15.881572099 +0100
***************
*** 770,775 ****
--- 770,776 ----
  HV_KVM_USE_CHROOT = "use_chroot"
  HV_CPU_MASK = "cpu_mask"
  HV_MEM_PATH = "mem_path"
+ HV_USBPASSTHROUGH = "usb_pass"
  HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX = "blockdev_prefix"
  HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR = "reboot_behavior"

***************
*** 824,829 ****
--- 825,831 ----
    HV_KVM_USE_CHROOT: VTYPE_BOOL,
    HV_CPU_MASK: VTYPE_STRING,
    HV_MEM_PATH: VTYPE_STRING,
+   HV_USBPASSTHROUGH: VTYPE_STRING,
    HV_BLOCKDEV_PREFIX: VTYPE_STRING,
    HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR: VTYPE_STRING,
    }
***************
*** 1809,1814 ****
--- 1811,1817 ----
      HV_MEM_PATH: "",
      HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR: INSTANCE_REBOOT_ALLOWED,
      HV_CPU_MASK: CPU_PINNING_ALL,
+     HV_USBPASSTHROUGH: "",
      },
    HT_FAKE: {
      },
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/: _generated_rpc.py
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/http: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/hypervisor: .dir
diff -r -c ganeti-2.6.0_original/lib/hypervisor/hv_kvm.py ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/hypervisor/hv_kvm.py
*** ganeti-2.6.0_original/lib/hypervisor/hv_kvm.py  2012-07-27 13:27:41.000000000 +0100
--- ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/hypervisor/hv_kvm.py   2012-10-04 13:46:54.993572107 +0100
***************
*** 490,495 ****
--- 490,496 ----
      constants.HV_VHOST_NET: hv_base.NO_CHECK,
      constants.HV_KVM_USE_CHROOT: hv_base.NO_CHECK,
      constants.HV_MEM_PATH: hv_base.OPT_DIR_CHECK,
+     constants.HV_USBPASSTHROUGH:  hv_base.NO_CHECK,
      constants.HV_REBOOT_BEHAVIOR:
        hv_base.ParamInSet(True, constants.REBOOT_BEHAVIORS),
      constants.HV_CPU_MASK: hv_base.OPT_MULTI_CPU_MASK_CHECK,
***************
*** 1257,1262 ****
--- 1258,1268 ----
      kvm_nics = instance.nics
      hvparams = hvp

+     usb_pass = instance.hvparams[constants.HV_USBPASSTHROUGH]
+     if usb_pass:
+         usb_pass_arr = usb_pass.split(";")
+         kvm_cmd.extend(["-usb", "-device", "usb-host,hostbus=%s,hostaddr=%s" % tuple(usb_pass_arr)])
+ 
      return (kvm_cmd, kvm_nics, hvparams)

    def _WriteKVMRuntime(self, instance_name, data):
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/impexpd: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/masterd: .dir
diff -r -c ganeti-2.6.0_original/lib/query.py ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/query.py
*** ganeti-2.6.0_original/lib/query.py  2012-07-27 12:31:48.000000000 +0100
--- ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/query.py   2012-10-04 13:46:26.625572103 +0100
***************
*** 1745,1750 ****
--- 1745,1751 ----
      constants.HV_NIC_TYPE: "NIC_type",
      constants.HV_PAE: "PAE",
      constants.HV_VNC_BIND_ADDRESS: "VNC_bind_address",
+     constants.HV_USBPASSTHROUGH: "usb_pass",
      }

    fields = [
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/rapi: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/server: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/tools: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/utils: .dir
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/: _vcsversion.py
Only in ganeti-2.6.0_changed/lib/watcher: .dir
```